# Simplify $\sqrt n+\frac {1}{\sqrt n}$ for $n=7+4\sqrt3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $n=7+4\sqrt3$,then what is the simplified value of 
$$\sqrt n+\frac {1}{\sqrt n}$$
I was taking LCM but how to get rid of  $\sqrt n$ in denominator

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint:  We have $\left(\sqrt n+\dfrac {1}{\sqrt n}\right)^2=n+2+\frac 1n$, then multiply top and bottom of the last by the conjugate.

Answer (score 2):

Square $2 + \sqrt{3}$, and you will know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Ross Millikan's answer is much more elegant, but I am posting this answer as well because it is in a sense more general.  (By this I mean it will work for *any* expression involving $\sqrt{n}$, and not just this epxression in particular.)  First, we make a guess that
$$
\sqrt{n} = a + b\sqrt{3}
$$

Squaring both sides, we find that
$$
7 + 4\sqrt{3} = a^2 + 3b^2 + 2ab\sqrt{3}
$$

Can you think of $a$ and $b$ integers that will make $a^2 + 3b^2 = 7$ and $2ab = 4$?  If so, you can write $\sqrt{n}$ in a nicer form and the expression should be simple to calculate.

(Note that this method doesn't always work.  But in general if you ever have a square root of a number of the form $x + y\sqrt{z}$, it can't hurt to *try* making $\sqrt{x + y\sqrt{z}} = x' + y'\sqrt{z}$.)

Comment: This is new one.Is there any other replacement like this for similar type of expression

Answer (score 0):

You could as OP suggests, add 2, and take the square root.

For example, $\dfrac{1}{(7+4\sqrt3)}$ is $(7-4 \sqrt3)$, so the sum of these numbers is $14$.  You add $2$ to it to get $16$, and take the square root.

The new number is $4 = x + \dfrac {1}x$,  which leads to $x = \dfrac{\sqrt{4+2} + \sqrt{4-2}}{2}$ = 1.93185165259.

Comment: Okay I'll look your method.I leave a comment if there is any problem.going to lunch.Thanks

Comment: The new number is $4 = x + 1/x$, not (x+1)/x.

Comment: okay sorry i didn't give attention on that